# How i can convert format date to d/M/yyyy and convert format time to h:mm:ss AM in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, converters, sqltransaction

I have created a field of type datetime. I want to display this in YYYY/M/D format

example

date 09/09/2014 to display as 2014/9/9

Also I need display a time field [Time_Orde] in this format 2:43:14 PM

I use SQL server 2008

I have tried the function

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

My code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,Order_Date) from Orders_Teakeaway
```

But I could not get this format 2014/9/9

Comment: which rdbms you are using?

Comment: Read your own question again and see if it makes any sense..`" I want to convert format date to: d / M /yyyy"`... then you said `"date 09/09/2014 to 9-9-2014 and right to left 2014-9-9 in sql converter"` , What exactly you want, could you not have simply said I have Datetime field which in such such format and I want it to be in such such format. Ask a question here not a riddle.

Comment: That, after converting the format to date : 2014/9/9
and for the time: 2:45:14 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single style number that will give you YYYY/M/D 2014/9/9

Try this:

```
convert(varchar(5),Order_Date,111) + replace(convert(varchar(5),Order_Date,1),'0','')
```

Style 111 is YYYY/MM/DD but we only take the first 5 chars (YYYY/)
Style 1 is MM/DD/YY but again we only take the first 5 chars (MM/DD)
then replace any zero's in the MM/DD part and concatenate

For the time, try this

```
  left(right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Time_Orde, 100),7),5)
+ left(right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(27), Time_Orde, 9),9),3)
+ right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Time_Orde, 100),2)
```

Comment: Nice function for format date, but, function of time hasn't worked select (convert (varchar, Time_Orde, 100), 12,7) from Orders

Comment: @SherifHamdy I have altered the time formatting, please try it